# How can I fill intersection of two (three) sets like this pictures?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to fill intersection of two (three) sets like this pictures, but I can't do that.
[image]

[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: Would this help -- http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/155308/34618

Comment: -1 for showing no research effort.

Comment: The duplicate given in the closing reason is one out of many others that can be found by just searching for `Venn` on this site.